# Keras custom loss function that uses hidden layer outputs as part of the objective

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to implement an autoencoder in Keras that not only minimizes the reconstruction error but its constructed features should also maximize a measure I define. I don't really have an idea of how to do this.

Here's a snippet of what I have so far:

```
corrupt_data = self._corrupt(self.data, 0.1)

# define encoder-decoder network structure
# create input layer
input_layer = Input(shape=(corrupt_data.shape[1], ))
encoded = Dense(self.encoding_dim, activation = "relu")(input_layer)
decoded = Dense(self.data.shape[1], activation="sigmoid")(encoded)

# create autoencoder
dae = Model(input_layer, decoded)

# define custom multitask loss with wlm measure
def multitask_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # extract learned features from hidden layer
    learned_fea = Model(input_layer, encoded).predict(self.data)
    # additional measure I want to optimize from an external function
    wlm_measure = wlm.measure(learned_fea, self.labels)
    cross_entropy = losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
    return wlm_measure + cross_entropy

# create optimizer
dae.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss=multitask_loss)

dae.fit(corrupt_data, self.data, 
                epochs=self.epochs, batch_size=20, shuffle=True, 
                callbacks=[tensorboard])

# separately create an encoder model
encoder = Model(input_layer, encoded)
```

Currently this does not work properly... When I viewed the training history the model seems to ignore the additional measure and train only based on the cross entropy loss. Also if I change the loss function to consider only wlm measure, I get the error "numpy.float64" object has no attribute "get_shape" (I don't know if changing my wlm function's return type to a tensor will help).

There are a few places that I think may have gone wrong. I don't know if I am extracting the outputs of the hidden layer correctly in my custom loss function. Also I don't know if my wlm.measure function is outputting correctly—whether it should output numpy.float32 or a 1-dimensional tensor of type float32.

Basically a conventional loss function only cares about the output layer's predicted labels and the true labels. In my case, I also need to consider the hidden layer's output (activation), which is not that straightforward to implement in Keras.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: here a simple solution to put intermediate layers in loss computation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62454500/how-to-use-tensorflow-custom-loss-for-a-keras-model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to define your `learned_fea` `Model` inside your custom loss function. Rather, you could define a single model upfront with two outputs: the output of the decoder (the reconstruction) and the output of the endoder (the feature representation):

```
multi_output_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[decoded, encoded])
```

Now you can write a custom loss function that only applies to the output of the encoder:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return wlm.measure(y_pred, y_true)
```

Upon compiling the model, you pass a list of loss functions (or a dictionary if you name your tensors):

```
model.compile(loss=['binary_crossentropy', custom_loss], optimizer=...)
```

And fit the model by passing a list of outputs:

```
model.fit(X=X, y=[data_to_be_reconstructed,labels_for_wlm_measure])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In that case, is the model fitted twice, each time with a different loss? Does the final model share the same encoding layer or are two different encoding layers trained? This looks like two separate models are being created but I may be wrong... In addition, if the encoding layer is shared for the two objectives, how do I specify which objective I want to favor? Say I care more for optimizing wlm_measure over optimizing reconstruction error, how do I do that?

Comment: No, just one model is created and optimized with respect to the average of the list of loss functions you provide. So there is only one 'shared' encoding layer. If you want to emphasize one loss function over the other, `model.compile()` has an argument `loss_weights` that lets you do this. Check out [the docs](https://keras.io/models/model/) for the details.

Comment: I see that makes a lot of sense! So now does my model make two outputs when I call predict? One output is the reconstructed features (output of the output layer) and the other output is the learned features (output of the encoder layer)?

Comment: Yes, `model.predict()` will return a list of predictions, exactly as you mention it.

Comment: Great! That solves the problem, thanks a lot! One last question: if I were to make a multi-output model, then I need to make wlm_measure as a separate loss. wlm_measure needs both the learned features of all samples (dimension is the encoding dimension) and an array of labels (dimension is the original dataset's dimension, i.e. number of samples) to compute it. That does not really match the y_true, y_pred format. In other words, I would need to access the learned features for all samples in order to compute the loss. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but the loss is always computed for batches of data and not for the entire dataset (the y_true, y_pred format). This also holds for the reconstruction loss. So wlm_measure will compute the loss for the feature representation of the current batch of data, and their associated labels.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I really wanted to ask is, for the y_true and y_pred parameters, are the y_pred of all samples in that batch being passed in, or is the y_pred of each sample in that batch passed in each time? I would need y_pred of all samples in the batch to compute the measure.

Comment: Yes, it is for all the samples in the batch.